# Why do rfind and find return the same values in Python 2.6.5?

Tags: python, find, substring

I'm relatively new to Python, and something is acting up.  Basically, when I call `str.rfind("test")` on a string, the output is the same as `str.find("test")`.  It's best that I show you an example:

```
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, May  6 2011, 17:25:59) 
[GCC 4.5.0 20100604 [gcc-4_5-branch revision 160292]] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import string
>>> line = "hello what's up"
>>> line.rfind("what")
6
>>> line.find("what")
6
```

By my understanding, the value of `line.find` is okay, but the value of `line.rfind` should be `9`.  Am I misinterpreting these functions or not using them well?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think you're expecting `rfind` to return the index of the rightmost character in the first/leftmost match for `"what"`. It actually returns the index of the leftmost character in the last/*rightmost* match for `"what`". To quote [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.rfind):

> #### `str.rfind(sub[, start[, end]])`
>
> Return the highest index in the string where substring *sub* is found, such that *sub* is contained within `s[start:end]`. Optional arguments *start* and *end* are interpreted as in slice notation. Return `-1` on failure.

`"ab c ab".find("ab")` would be `0`, because the leftmost occurrence is on the left end.
`"ab c ab".rfind("ab")` would be `5`, because the rightmost occurrence is starts at that index.

Comment: Thanks, I read the documentation but completely did not catch on to that subtlety.  I guess I'll have to add the length of my search term to get that index. Thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

**find()** will return the index of the first match. But **rfind** will give you the last occurence of the pattern. It will be clear if you try to match repeated match case.

check this Example

```
       >>> string='hey! how are you harish'
       >>>string.find('h')
       >>>0                #it matched for first 'h' in the string
       >>> string.rfind('h')    
           22             #it matched for the last 'h' in the string
```

Answer (score 3):

To understand better what `.rfind` is meant for, try your example with a string like "hello what's up, hello what's up" (that is, more than 1 occurrence of "what")